# Elasticsearch 5.6 aggregation avg by terms not all buckets returned

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the following query on ES 5.6 :

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "description.keyword"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_source": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "flux.source.idname.keyword",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "description_avg": {
          "avg": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "source": "doc['description.keyword'].toString().length()"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which works for what I'm trying to do (display description length avg by source) but I can only see 6 buckets as a result :

[image]

Any idea why ?

Thanks in advance,
Julien

Comment: How many documents do have the `flux.source.idname.keyword` field? Can you run an exists query on that field? My guess is 16 out of 1149438

Comment: Indeed, I had to use `flux.source.name.keyword` instead. Thanks !

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> {   "size": 0,   "query": {
> "exists": {
> "field": "description.keyword"
> }   },   "aggs": {
> "group_by_source": {
> "terms": {
> "field": "flux.source.name.keyword",
> "size": 1000
> },
> "aggs": {
> "description_avg": {
> "avg": {
> "script": {
> "lang": "painless",
> "source": "doc['description.keyword'].toString().length()"
> }
> }
> }
> }
> }   } }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.